# Factories assign association after created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a question in Rails 4.

On my **factories.rb** i have something like:

```
factory :user do
   sequence(:name)   { |n| "User #{n}" }
   sequence(:email)  { |n| "user_#{n}@example.org" }
   password 'foobar'
   password_confirmation 'foobar'
end
```

The problem, i don't know to add a relation after created user.

When i create a user, and he is a **moderator** i assign to user the role like that:

```
u.add_role_id!(11)
```

I have different table for relationships, with **user_id** and **role_id** and on user model i have the method.

```
def add_role_id!(role)
   role_user_relationship.create!(role_id: Role.find(role).id)
end
```

How i do that on **factories.rb**?

Now what i now to do:

```
u = FactoryGirl.create(:moderator)
u.add_role_id!(11)
```

I want to assign by default on **factories.rb**

How I do that?!

Thanks everybody!

Manu

#### Solution:

I have to add these lines:

```
after(:create) do |u|
  u.add_roles_ids!([10,20,30])
end
```

With the entire code:

```
factory :user do
   sequence(:name)   { |n| "User #{n}" }
   sequence(:email)  { |n| "user_#{n}@mudev.org" }
   password 'foobar'
   password_confirmation 'foobar'

   after(:create) do |u|
      u.add_roles_ids!([10,20,30])
   end
end
```

Thanks to Peter Alfvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FactoryGirl's `after` callback mechanism described at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks to get the comparable behavior to what you're doing now by including the following within your factory definition:

```
after(:create) {|u| u.add_role_id!(11)
```

Depending on your validation, you can alternatively do this `after(:build)` or `before(:create)`.